# Display custom attributes in related products on single product page

Tags: php, magento

I need to display a custom attribute in the related.phtml for the related products on a single product page. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please be more specific. Your question is rather vague. Please be aware that nobody can read your mind or see what is on your screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please Make sure in custom attribute `Used in Product Listing` set to `YES` from Manage Attributes section
2. In related.phtml you can ftech attribute value in following way:

   `echo $_item->getData("test_attibute");   //Here test_attibute is attribute code`

   OR

   `echo $_item->getTestAttibute()   //Here test_attibute is attribute code`

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot brother this helped me a lot and saved me a lot of time. Very helpful from you. Thanks again.